# How to save topics in file?

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to save these topics in file :/amcl/parameter_descriptions
/amcl/parameter_updates

what can i do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164541/how-to-save-topics-in-file?/) by [yasamin](https://answers.ros.org/users/14581/yasamin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosbag is the thing you are looking for.

http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag

Good described in [this tutorial.](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Recording%20and%20playing%20back%20data)

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yasamin](https://answers.ros.org/users/14581/yasamin/) on 2014-05-14**:
Thank you I have a problem with these :rosbag record -a when i type these command give me these error :[ WARN] [1400075193.299487382]: /use_sim_time set to true and no clock published. Still waiting for valid time...

what can i do??

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-14**:
It sounds like you have (or had) a simulator running, but for some reason it isn't publishing the clock topic, or your rosbag node can't subscribe to it. You should make sure the simulator is running, and see if there are any messages published to /clock